# Gulp - Merge Two JSON file and create Angular Configuration file

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using `gulp-ng-constant` to create a `config.json` file for my angular project using below code:

*****UPDATED CODE*******

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    ngConfig = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
    baseDest = '../app',
    extend = require("gulp-extend"),
    pkg = require('./package.json');

gulp.task('config', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/config.json')
        .pipe(extend('./src/timezone.json')
        .pipe(ngConfig({
            name: pkg.name + '.config'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(baseDest + 'js/'))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

});

// OUTPUT IS STILL SAME
```

and its work great and create a JSON file from me, something like,

```
angular.module("app.config",[]).constant("ID","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")}});
```

But now, i have more files to configure, except for `config.json`

So is there any way to first merge all the JSON files into one and then create a `configuration` file using `gulp`.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge `JSON`s via `gulp`. Look at the `gulp-jsoncombine` or `gulp-extend`.

Comment: I tried. Gulp runs fine(with no error). But the generated file doesn't contains the second JSON file data.

Comment: What you have tried? I can't see any of the plug-ins mentioned above in your code.

Comment: Thanks, i finally solve this issue. The problem was trivial. In extend, i need to pass the output file name and need to add `timezone.json` in gulp.src.  `gulp.src(['./src/config.json','./src/timezone.json']).pipe(extend('config.json'))`.  
Since you provide the suggestion of using `gulp-extend`. I am accepting your answer. :)